# Uncaught TypeError: this.setHours is not a function when i try to setDate in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, dom, format

I try to add 1 day to a date and i face an error "Uncaught TypeError: this.setHours is not a function" when i do this:

```
if (lastTemp == "00:00") {
    console.log(lastElemDay);//2020-07-17
    var date = new Date('"' + lastElemDay + '"');
    console.log(date);//Fri Jul 17 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0200

    var lastElemDay = new Date();

    console.log(date.getDate() + 1);//18
    //the error is here when i  "setDate"
    lastElemDay.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
}
```

Can you help me?

Thanks by advance

Comment: Cant find `this.setHours` in your code

Comment: `new Date('"' + lastElemDay + '"')` is wrong, it should just be `new Date(lastElemDay)`

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen no this is a common library

epascarello no differences with or without

Comment: Nothing to do with jQuery or DOM.

Comment: `new Date('"' + '2020-07-17' + '"')` returns an invalid date in Safari at least. Calling *setDate* on an invalid date returns NaN, it doesn't throw an error.

Comment: You appear to be declaring *lastElemDay* twice. If the first declaration (not shown in the OP) is with *let* or *const* then the second declaration (even with *var*) will throw an error.